# Does firemonkey app made with delphi (ARM native code) work on bluestack?

Tags: android, delphi, arm, firemonkey, bluestacks

Does Firemonkey app made with Delphi work on Bluestack (under Windows 10)? those kinds of apps are native in the way they contain native code compiled for ARM CPU (not java). I try on MSI app player (that internally use Bluestack) and it's didn't work :( maybe I miss something?

Comment: see if this helps: https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/running-delphi-applications-on-android-intel

Answer (score 0):

Bluestacks can run APK files. Even if the apps are ARM native but not Android packages (APKs), they won't run. If they are in fact Android packages, verify that the target API version is correct (i.e. the Android version that the app runs on).

Comment: I download my app from the google play store so I think now as all apps are APKs so it's must work. Yes the target API is correct

Comment: @loki Then you should try another Android emulator such as MEmu, Genymotion, etc or you should install Android x86 in a VM, using VirtualBox or VMWare.

Comment: I never managed to run an android app in Bluestack. How did you do it?

Comment: you must set run ARM code to true in bluestacks :)